# disable_functions php.ini eval function still work

Tags: php, eval

I got a little problem trying to disable some function in my php. 
First of all, i`m not the owner of the server so I can't change the master php.ini configuration. But I tried to change it with the directive the server owner give me.

Here is the line I put in the php.ini file I created

```
disable_functions=eval,exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source
```

in my `phpinfo()` I can see in the local value and the master value that those function are disabled.

But my problem start here. 
In the same file in witch i run the `phpinfo()` and I can confirm that the function are supposed to be disabled, I run an `eval()` and a `shell_exec()` and the `eval()` still work but the `shel_exec()` is disabled.

**Why can't I disable `eval()`?**

Comment: Does your server run `suPHP?` if so, you'll need to enable it in your .htaccess file `<IfModule mod_suphp.c> suPHP_ConfigPath /home/USERNAME/public_html </IfModule>` for instance. This will ensure that the php.ini settings to take effect recursively throughout your directories.

Comment: I do a 
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath path/to/my/php.ini/
</IfModule>
so i guess i have suphp that work on the server
Also I change my description, the shell_exec doesn't work anymore but the eval still work

Comment: have you restarted apache ?

Comment: This is not my server so I can't really restart apache. I still wonder why eval work but all the other function are disabled (I didn't try them all but I tried shell_exec,curl_exec and they are disabled)

Comment: There are two php.ini sometimes, one for command-line interface and one for apache. /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini or sudo vi /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini. Maybe you are modifying the wrong one. And of course you need to restart apache.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`eval` is a language construct, not a function, so it can't be disabled. See http://www.php.net/eval for more info.

Comment: yikes! this is bad news... al hacker scripts have an eval()

Comment: If you use suhosin patch then you can disable eval using suhosin configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can try building https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_diseval_extension to disable eval.